# How can I get different statistics for a rolling datetime range up top a current value in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe that has four different columns and looks like the table below:

`index_example | column_a | column_b | column_c |    datetime_column

      1              A        1,000        1        2020-01-01 11:00:00
      2              A        2,000        2        2019-11-01 10:00:00
      3              A        5,000        3        2019-12-01 08:00:00
      4              B        1,000        4        2020-01-01 05:00:00
      5              B        6,000        5        2019-01-01 01:00:00
      6              B        7,000        6        2019-04-01 11:00:00
      7              A        8,000        7        2019-11-30 07:00:00
      8              B          500        8        2020-01-01 05:00:00
      9              B        1,000        9        2020-01-01 03:00:00
      10             B        2,000        10       2020-01-01 02:00:00
      11             A        1,000        11       2019-05-02 01:00:00`

**Purpose:**

For each row, get the different rolling statistics for `column_b` based on a window of time in the `datetime_column` defined as the last N months. The window of time to look at however, is filtered by the value in `column_a`.

Code example using a for loop which is not feasible given the size:

```
mean_dict = {}
for index,value in enumerate(df.datetime_column)):
    test_date = value
    test_column_a = df.column_a[index]
    subset_df = df[(df.datetime_column<test_date)&\ 
                (df.datetime_column>=test_date-timedelta(days = 180))&
                 (df.column_a == test_column_a)]
    mean_dict[index] = df.column_b.mean()
```

For example for row #1:

- Target date = 2020-01-01 11:00:00
- Target value in column_a = A
- Date Range: from 2019-07-01 11:00:00 to 2020-01-01 11:00:00
- Average would be the mean of rows 2,3,7

If I wanted average for row #2 then it would be:

- Target date = 2019-11-01 10:00:00
- Target value in column_a = A
- Date Range: from 2019-05-01 10:00 to 2019-11-01 10:00:00
- Average would be the mean of rows 11

and so on...

I cannot use the `grouper` since in reality I do not have dates but datetimes.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Thanks!

---

EDIT
The dataframe is big ~2M rows which means that looping is not an option. I already tried looping and creating a subset based on conditional values but it takes too long.

Comment: I have difficulty in understanding your question. Could you read through carefully and see if you are putting out clearly what you are looking for?

Comment: @SathishSanjeevi I have refactored the question, does it make more sense?

Comment: @JuanDaza could you just add expected `dataframe`? [JFYI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)